# URL from json adding a trailing slash

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON element that contains a URL:

```
"http://media.xyz.com/Data/stockPhotos/17962.jpg"
```

But when I try to use it in my javascript:

```
imgRow += "<td><img src=" + item.style.stockPhotoUrl + "/></td>";
```

The result is:

```
<td>
    <img src="http://media.xyz.com/Data/stockPhotos/17962.jpg/"/>
</td>
```

I'm not sure why this is adding a trailing slash.

How can I get rid or this slash?

Comment: `"/></td>"` I think you might need a space here `" /></td>"`?

Comment: @thefourtheye - dang!  that was it...  So simple.  Thank you.  If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: as a side note, you do not need the closing / on the image tag. (see [void elements](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/html-void-elements.htm).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML tag attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attr-value-double-quoted) are supposed to be wrapped in double quotes.

The behavior you are getting is probably a product of not wrapping the src attribute.  Try modifying your javascript to this:

```
imgRow += "<td><img src=\"" + item.style.stockPhotoUrl + "\"/></td>";
```

or, using single quotes for string representation:

```
imgRow += '<td><img src="' + item.style.stockPhotoUrl + '"/></td>';
```

Comment: can also use single quotes ...and if value contains no space quotes aren't essential

Comment: Beat me to it. OP, this is what you should be doing. The image tag has quotation marks surrounding the url which you do not include in your code. @charlietfl they may not be essential, but down the road, that url changes and includes a space, and the image won't be seen again

Comment: Obviously browsers are forgiving in what they'll allow - we can file this under "good practices".  Does anyone happen to use single-quotes as their standard?